# SSH connection issue to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, telnet, ssh-keys

I am using cygwin which has ssh configured.

- I am using a windows machine 
  Path to keypair file : C:\cygwin64\home\suhelkhan.ssh\kworld_kp1.pem
- The EC2 instance is Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6
- The EC2 is correctly mapped to the keypair
- The security group associated with this EC2 instances allows  for SSH
  connection.

[image]

I am using the following command to connect

```
suhelkhan@DTDVD0003009PR ~/.ssh
$ ssh -vvv "kworld_kp1.pem" ec2-user@ec2-52-63-yyy-zz.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

output:

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug2: resolving "kworld_kp1.pem" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname kworld_kp1.pem: Name or service not known
```

Checking with telnet gives the following:

```
suhelkhan@DTDVD0003009PR ~/.ssh
$ telnet 52.63.141.40
Trying 52.63.141.40...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

The Telnet cmd gives out the following:
    suhelkhan@DTDVD0003009PR ~/.ssh
    $ telnet HOST 22
    Can't lookup hostname HOST

Comment: what you get for telnet 52.63.141.40 22

Comment: @error2007s . Thanks of the response , i get the response as below:
`
homepc@SuhelKhan ~
$ telnet 52.63.141.40 22
Trying 52.63.141.40...
Connected to 52.63.141.40.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
`
Was this to just check if Telnet is working ?

Answer (score 0):

I just redid the whole thing (New instance with appropriate security group, Proper Key-Pair match up and new cygwin installation [http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/installing-amazon-web-services-command-line-interface-aws-cli-for-windows-os-x-and-linux-2/ ]) .Also added my Public IP to the inbound tab of the security group i am using.. all works.. thanks for the all the help